# Allow events to be autoloaded from URL Webform CiviCRM does not seem to work

Tags: webform-civicrm

OK my webform has a couple of test events all public and a single contact, The event is set to register all contacts for the same event. The contact is able to register for one event, user select.  The event is set to autopopulate from the URL, my url is in the form form/{form-alias}?event1=254

The events list on the form as radio buttons.

And it's just not populating the event, that is the correct radio button is not highlighed, nor is the correct event selected if its in listing format.
Am I missing something?

Using Civicrm 5.67 and Drupal 10.  Webform 6.2.4.

https://lgf2.xpdient.co.uk/form/my-test-webform?event1=254

Comment: I feel like *I'm* missing something when reading this. It starts out in the middle of a thought "OK..." and uses "etc etc" as if we all can read your mind. Can you please clarify your setup, Drupal & Civi version, screenshot the form you've created, and describe in more detail what you mean by "just not selecting the event"?

Comment: Edited as requested.

Comment: Hi COleman works fine on a local setup - must be the server environment or a module clash. I'll sort it and post an answer for folks.

Comment: Ok, good to hear you're making progress!

Answer (score 2):

If the method on the webform

[image]

is set to

1. '**Register all contacts for the same event(s)**' then use node/484?event1=254 or node/484?event2=251
2. '**Register each contact separately**' then use node/484?c1event1=254 or node/484?c1event1=254,252

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Thanks Pradeep. I did do as the webform guidance suggests and it’s just not playing.

Comment: Is it okay to provide the look link if it's a public form?

Comment: Hi Pradeep - I just did a vanilla install using MAMP and it works fine - must be something in server environment or a module clash somewhere. I'll investigate and post an answer in case someone else comes across this

Answer (score 0):

I did spend 5 hours on this and the error was totally repeatable on several forms. Now I have built a new form and everything works just fine. I'm at a loss to explain. Sorry to waste everyone's valuable time.

Comment: and was the Event set to 'user selects' in each case?